# ASP.Net core 1 list files in given directory

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I need to list all files that are present in a given folder, using C# for ASP.Net core 1. Something like `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` in earlier versions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            pathToFolder, 
            "*" , 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
            )
        {
            // do something

        }
```

note that I'm recursing child directories too which may or may not be what you want

Comment: But "Directory.EnumerateFiles" belongs to System.IO namespace which is not found in .Net core

Comment: That's not true, see here http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=EnumerateFiles. It lists you the packages where EnumerateFiles is available. This makes it easy to add it as a dependency

Comment: I see it and the version of all packages is the same "4.0.1-rc2-24027" which I try it before and it told me it is not supported in .Net core.

Comment: @bilal1409 suspect something wrong in your project.json, post that so we can see it

Comment: Worked like a charm in the first try. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

in asp.net core to list or search files you can use this way:

for example consider we want to find latest update file in this directory:

```
public IActionResult Get(IFileProvider fileProvider)
 {
      var files = fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("wwwroot/updates");

      var latestFile =
                files
                .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastModified)
                .FirstOrDefault();

      return Ok(latestFile?.Name);
 }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-1.0)