# how to show all images from server directory in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show all images (which is in `"~/files/ "` folder) in asp.net mvc 5. It was like that:

```
public ActionResult uploadPartial()
{
     var appData = Server.MapPath("~/files");
     var images = Directory.GetFiles(appData).Select(x => new imagesviewmodel
     {
        Url = Url.Content("/files/" + Path.GetFileName(x))
     });
     return View(images);
}
```

and in view

```
@model IEnumerable<ckeditortest.Models.imagesviewmodel>

@foreach (var image in Model)
{
    <a href="#" class="returnImage" data-url="@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@image.Url">
        <img src="@image.Url" alt="Hejsan" id="#image" data-source="@image.Url" width="200" height="200"/>
    </a>
}
```

But in asp.net core i don't know how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You want [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37547113/1672458) for an example. You'll also have to replace `Server.MapPath`, as it's not available in .NET Core. You can use [this code](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core) to do that (inject `IHostingEnvironment` and get `WebRootPath` from it).

Using both of the above, you get this code (untested):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;
        var appData = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "files");

        var models = Directory.EnumerateFiles(appData).Select(x => new imagesviewmodel
        {
            Url = Url.Content(x)
        });

        return View(models);
    }
}
```

You can replace `GetLeftPart` with this (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40727571/1672458)):

```
Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.StrongAuthority, UriFormat.Unescaped)
```

Comment: Thanks your answer ! I will test it as soon as possible. Another quesstion how can I change this code @Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@image.Url  ---- in view ? for asp.net core

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov I've updated the answer with that info.

Comment: Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.StrongAuthority, UriFormat.Unescaped) is not worked